# crossfilter multiple grouping

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

My data is like this.

```
{ date : "25-1-2012",
  sentiment : "Positive", could be positive,negative or neutral
  year: 2012
}
```

My code is like this

```
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
```

what I want to achieve is grouping on date where I would be able to know on all date how many sentiments were positive and how many were negative.
Then I want to use dates as x-axis and count of positive,negative and neutral on that date as Y-axis
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to use date as X-axis and count of positive ,negative and
>   neutral on that specific date as Y-axis in linechart of dc.js – 
>   user3614894

If you need it to display it using dc.js I would use reduce, see example at http://jsbin.com/fisawaqa/2/edit

```
var ndx = crossfilter(sentimentData);
var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.date;
});
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    console.log(v);
    ++p.count;
    p.positive += v.sentiment == "Positive" ? 1 : 0;
    p.negative += v.sentiment == "Negative" ? 1 : 0;
    p.neutral += v.sentiment == "Neutral" ? 1 : 0;
    return p;
}
function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    --p.count;
    p.positive -= v.sentiment == "Positive" ? 1 : 0;
    p.negative -= v.sentiment == "Negative" ? 1 : 0;
    p.neutral -= v.sentiment == "Neutral" ? 1 : 0;
    return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return {count: 0, positive: 0,negative:0,neutral:0};
}
var dateGroup = dateDimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd,reduceRemove,reduceInitial);
```

Comment: Interesting, the SO answer velocity filter allows a two hour, 30 some minute interval to elapse. Makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Create two dimensions by date and sentiment, filter by date, then group by sentiment:

```
"use strict";

var data = [
    { date: "25-1-2012",
        sentiment: "Positive",
        year: 2012
    },
    { date: "25-1-2012",
        sentiment: "Negative",
        year: 2012
    },
    { date: "25-1-2012",
        sentiment: "Positive",
        year: 2012
    },
    { date: "26-1-2012",
        sentiment: "Positive",
        year: 2012
    },
    { date: "27-1-2012",
        sentiment: "Negative",
        year: 2012
    }
];

var ndx  = crossfilter(data);

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
dateDim.filterExact("25-1-2012");
var sentimentDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.sentiment;});
var sentimentGroup = sentimentDim.group().reduceCount();
console.log(sentimentGroup.top(Infinity));
```

Comment: I wanted to use date as X-axis and count of positive ,negative and neutral on that specific date as Y-axis in linechart of dc.js